# Flutter: Async function in Getx Controller takes no effect when initialized

Tags: flutter, async-await, aws-amplify, flutter-getx

**Updates:**

2021/06/11 **After hours of debugging yesterday, I confirmed that the problem is caused by aws amplify configuration: `_configureAmplify()`. Because the location of the amplify server was set wrong, so `_configureAmplify()` takes several seconds to work... and therefore, the `readPost()` function did not work on initialization, as it must run after `_configureAmplify()`...**

2021/06/10*I made changes to my code according to S. M. JAHANGIR's advice, and updated the question. The issue still presists. The value of `posts` is not updated when called in initialization and the data only shows up after reload. (if I commented out the _controller.readPost() in UI, the value of `posts` is always empty.*

---

I have this page that loads information from aws amplify with getx implemented. However, I found out the `readPost() async` funtion in getx controller dart file is not reading from database, when the controller instance is initialized. I have to add a `_controller.readPost()` in UI file to make it work. And the data only shows up after a reload of that UI page...

Getx Controller dart file:

```
class ReadPostController extends GetxController {
  var isLoading = true.obs;
  var posts = <Posty>[].obs;

  @override
  void onInit() {
    _configureAmplify();
    await readPost();
    super.onInit();
    // print('show post return value: $posts');
  }

  void _configureAmplify() {
    final provider = ModelProvider();
    final dataStorePlugin = AmplifyDataStore(modelProvider: provider);
    AmplifyStorageS3 storage = new AmplifyStorageS3();
    AmplifyAuthCognito auth = new AmplifyAuthCognito();
    AmplifyAPI apiRest = AmplifyAPI();

    // Amplify.addPlugin(dataStorePlugin);
    Amplify..addPlugins([dataStorePlugin, storage, auth, apiRest]);
    Amplify.configure(amplifyconfig);
    print('Amplify configured');
  }    

// read all posts from databases
  Future readPost() async {
    try {
      isLoading(true);
      var result = await Amplify.DataStore.query(Posty.classType);
      print('finish loading request');
      result = result.sublist(1);
      posts.assignAll(result);
      // print(the value of posts is $posts');
    } finally {
      isLoading(false);
    }
  }

  @override
  void onClose() {
    // called just before the Controller is deleted from memory
    super.onClose();
  }
}
```

And in the UI part:

```
class TabBody extends StatelessWidget {
  TabBody({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  final ReadPostController _controller = Get.put(ReadPostController());

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    _controller.readPost();//if commented out, _controller.post is empty
    return Container(
        child: Obx(
      () => Text('showing：${_controller.posts[1].title}'),
    ));
  }
}
```

In my understanding, the `readPost()` function should be called when the `ReadPost_controller` is initiallized. And the UI will update when the `posts = <Posty>[].obs` changes. Guys, what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, when you are calling `readPost` on `onInit` you are not awaiting. So change it to:

```
onInit() async{
 ...
 await readPost();
 ... 
}
```

Secondly, `posts` is a RxList so you need to use the `assignAll` method to update it.
Therefore, in your `readPost` method, instead of `posts.value = reault` you need to use `posts.assignAll(result)`

- Calling from the UI works because `readPost` every time the `build` method is called by the Flutter framework and actually the UI shows the data from every previous call.

Comment: Hi Jahangir, thank you for your answer. I have updated my code according to you advice. However the problem persists. I have updated my question. My guess is that maybe amplify returns the value too slow?

Comment: Are you sure that `await readPost();` isn't being called on `onInit`? Does `'finish loading request'` prints on console? Please let me know! And it's better to call `final ReadPostController _controller = Get.put(ReadPostController());` on the widget's build method than directly on class.

Comment: Dear Jahangir, thanks for the follow-up. After hours of debugging yesterday, I confirmed that the problem is caused by aws amplify configuration: `_configureAmplify()`. Because the location of the amplify server was set wrong, so `_configureAmplify()` takes several seconds to work... and therefore, the `readPost()` function did not work on initialization...

Comment: So now after configure properly, everything's working fine? Please confirm

Comment: Hi Jahangir, thank you for your follow-up. Yes, I wrote an isolate to make sure `_configureAmplify()` finishes configuration before calling `readPost()`, and it works fine. Thank you for your answer and I think it helped me for my debugging.

Answer (score 0):

I think try with GetBuilder instead of Obx.

```
GetBuilder<ReadPostController>(
builder: (value) => Text('showing：${value.posts[1].title}'),
)
```

and also use update(). in readPost() method.

Comment: GetBuilder is for simple state management. Won't work with Rx

Comment: did you try this way?